# Android detect when the application is paused

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm implementing an application witch need to run a task periodically, but its only needed if the application is in foreground.
So i'd like to remove the periodic handler callbacks on application pause and resume on restart.
There is any easy way of doing that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Call [removeCallbacks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and vice versa in onResume().

Comment: But if the app have several activities how can I do it?

Comment: Have a common base class for those activities that share this kind of behavior?